# GraphQL - syntax for where array is empty

Tags: graphql, prisma

What would be the correct syntax to obtain results where a reference array in GraphQL is empty?

Take this pseudo schema for example:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  tags: [Tag]!
}

type Tag {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  users: [User]!
}
```

I would want to retrieve all User objects which have no tags. Is this possible?

I am using Prisma, so I'm looking for an equivalent of this from their docs (https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-scalar-lists-arrays):

```
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    tags: {
      isEmpty: true,
    },
  },
})
```

but in a GraphQL query syntax rather than at resolver level.

Comment: I don't know of a way through which you could achieve this in GraphQL Syntax, what's the issue in doing this in resolver?

Comment: No issue, just a preference - might be a preference I'll have to do without by the sounds of things though :)

Also as an aside - it appears the Prisma documentation I linked to regarding the `isEmpty: true` only applies to scalar lists rather than relationships, so that isn't feasible anyway - but I'm sure there would be another way at that level.

Answer (score 1):

I have now found that you can use the following pattern to achieve this (using the same sample schema in the question):

`query { users (where: { tags_none: {} }) { id } }`

(Thank you engineers at Prisma for the assistance!)